# Jquery ajax call - collecting response details remotely

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to be able to debug issues with making jquery ajax calls to page methods within an ASP.NET application that only seem to happen on a handful of (remote) customer's machines.

This is easy locally - using for example Firebug to examine the response object interactively, but how can i get at this information remotely? Even if I handle the error callback, I still need to put that information somewhere, which is another page method invocation - but its the page method calls that are failing in the first place!

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could use ELMAH to log all the errors on your site, and then use its web interface to browse through those errors.

Comment: @user974235: Define "javascript error responses". If you're talking about when an AJAX call has an error, then that's actually a server-side thing. If the exception is allowed to percolate to the top level, then ELMAH will log it. If not, wherever you are catching the exception you need to log it yourself. If you're talking about an exception that gets thrown by your javascript after the response returns successfully, that won't get picked up by ELMAH.

Comment: It would be the AJAX response code, i.e. when its not 200, and its received at the browser afaik so would need to be a client side solution?

Comment: @user974235: The server decides what type of response it's sending to the client. The error response is either sent by your application directly, or because ASP.NET has had some problem (e.g. with invoking the page method). In the former case, you should be able to log the issue when it occurs. In the latter case, ELMAH will handle and log the error.